# add input field when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a form for adding recipe where there is ingredients button. A recipe can have many ingredients. When that button is clicked an input field for adding ingredients should be appear beneath ingredient button. What i tried to do is?

[image]

```
import Input from './Input.jsx';

export default class Sell extends Component {
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
          inputValues : {}
        }
        this.onHandleSubmit =this.onHandleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onChange( name, { target : { value } })
    {
         const inputValues = this.state.inputValues;
         inputValues[name] = value;
         this.setState({ inputValues })
    }

    onHandleSubmit()
    {
        console.log('clicked');
        const name = `ingrediant-${Object.keys(this.state.inputValues).length}`;
        let inputbox = <Input name={ name }
                              onChange={ this.onChange.bind(this, name )} />

    }

    onSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <h2 className="flow-text text-center">Add Recipe</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="col offset-s4 s4">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s12">
                      <input ref="name" id="name" type="text" className="validate flow-text" />
                      <label htmlFor="name">Name of Recipe</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div className="input-field col s12">
                        <a onClick={this.onHandleSubmit} className="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-block"><i className="material-icons right">add</i>Ingredients</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {this.state.inputValues}
                  <div className="row">
                    <button className="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-block">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can i create new dynamic(different ref for newly created input box) input field for ingredients when button is clicked?

Comment: @AvraamMavridis to send to the server. Because if user added 5 ingredients then all those 5 ingredients should have different ref to send to the server. Please correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: I dont see it been used, you dont do anywhere `this.refs`

Comment: I haven't done onSubmit task yet because i could not add field for ingredients when the button is clicked. I have used ref in my register page like this let email = this.refs.email.value.trim();
  let password = this.refs.password.value.trim();
  let confirmPassword = this.refs.confirmPassword.value.trim();
  if(password === confirmPassword && password !== "" && confirmPassword !== ""){
   let Info = {
    email:email,
    password:password
   };
   Accounts.createUser(Info, (er) => {
    if(er){
     ...
    }else {
      FlowRouter.go('/');
     }
   });
  }else{
  ..
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would make the input a separate component like

```
class Input extends Component
{

    render()
    {
      const { name, onChange } = this.props;
      return(<div className="row">
                <div className="input-field col s12">
                  <input id={name} 
                         type="text" 
                         className="validate flow-text" 
                         onChange={ this.props.onChange } />
                  <label htmlFor={name}>Name of Recipe</label>
                </div>
         </div>)
    }

}
```

And pass an onChange callback from the `Sell` component, the `Sell` component will maintain the values of the inputs, and when you want to send the values to the server you have it on the state. Something like:

```
class Sell extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
          inputValues = {},
          inputs : []
        }
    }

    onChange( name, { target : { value } })
    {
         const inputValues = this.state.inputValues;
         inputValues[name] = value;
         this.setState({ inputValues })
    }

    onHandleSubmit()
    {
        const name = `incrediant-${this.state.inputs.length}`;
        let inputbox = <Input name={ name }
                              key={this.state.inputs.length}
                              onChange={ this.onChange.bind(this, name )} />

       const inputs = this.state.inputs;
       inputs.push( inputbox );
       this.setState( { inputs } );

    }

   ...
   ....

   render()
   {
       ...
       ...
       {
           this.state.inputs.map( i => i );
       }
   }

}
```

In that case you dont have to keep `refs`

Comment: after clicking an ingredient button, new input field did not appear.

Comment: i get this error Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}).

Comment: @milan  you have to render it, I didnt add it to my answer to be more brief, you can do something like `this.state.inputs.push( <Input />)` and then use `map` in your render function. like `{ this.state.inputs.map( i => i ) }`

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. You removed Object.keys(). Can i know the reason?

Comment: Using Object.keys the name was not updated with new length but it is now updating with new length.

Comment: @milan since he have the other length, of an array and not an object, it is clearer without Object.keys. Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: How can i fetch those ingredients values ? To fetch name of recipe and price in onSubmit i can do event.target.name.value and event.target.price.value so i can send this to server.

Comment: @milan I am not sure what you mean, but you can probably have two different handlers, like `onPriceChange` and `onRecipeChange` and do their the same more or less stuff. You can open another question for that adding the code that you already have done, because this question/answer is already "stabilized"

Comment: sorry i forgot to bind this context .Now i could send data to the srver but i wanted to send only values not key, as an array so can you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544149/how-to-send-ingredients-data-to-the-server