# How to send ingredients data to the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a recipe form where there is add more button for ingredients because a recipe contains multiple ingredients. I need to pass these data to the server. I am using Meteor for backend. I could pass all the data like name, description, price, estimated delivery, to the server but could not send ingredients to the Recipe collection(or server). How can i send ingredients to the server as it contains multiple data ?

**My code is**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from './Input.jsx';

export default class Sell extends Component {
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
          inputValues : {},
          inputs:[]
        }
        this.onHandleSubmit =this.onHandleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onChange( name, { target : { value } })
    {
         const inputValues = this.state.inputValues;
         inputValues[name] = value;
         this.setState({ inputValues })
    }

    onHandleSubmit()
    {
        const name = `ingrediant-${this.state.inputs.length}`;
        let inputbox = <Input name={ name }
                              number={ this.state.inputs.length }   
                              key={ name }
                              onChange={ this.onChange.bind(this, name )} />

        const inputs = this.state.inputs;
        inputs.push(inputbox);
        this.setState({ inputs });
    }

    onSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let nameOfRecipe = event.target.name.value; 
        let description = event.target.description.value; 
        let price = event.target.name.value; 
        let estimatedDelivery = event.target.delivery.value; 
        let ingredients = this.state.inputValues;
        Meteor.call('Recipe.insert', nameOfRecipe, description, price, estimatedDelivery, ingredients, (err) => {
            if(err){
                Materialize.toast(err.reason,2500);
            }else{
                FlowRouter.go('/');
            }
        });
    }

    render() {

        );
    }
}
```

**server.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'Recipes.insert':(nameOfRecipe, description, price, estimatedDelivery, ingredients) => {
        let recipe={
            user:Meteor.user(),
            createdAt:new Date(),
            nameOfRecipe:nameOfRecipe,
            description:description,
            price:price,
            estimatedDelivery:estimatedDelivery,
            ingredients:ingredients,
            likes:[],
            comments:[]
        }
        Recipes.insert(recipe);
    }
});
```

code for sending data to the server is in onSubmit().

Comment: Send them as an array. You should decide on a de-normalization strategy, which is a fairly broad topic. There are MongoDB operators that will allow you to manipulate this array (or set) later if you need to. And don't embed the entire `user` object in your recipe.

Comment: if i do this.state.inputValues to send as an array i get an error of undefined.

Comment: This is probably not a normal array. Map it into an array of plain objects/strings.

Comment: How about JSON? That should be adequate for sending complex data-structures.

Comment: my JSON looks like this   "nameOfRecipe": "aloo chat",
  "description": "homemade aloo chat",
  "ingredients": {
    "ingrediant-0": "tomato",
    "ingrediant-1": "onion"
  },
  "price": "100",
  "estimatedDelivery": "10",
  "likes": [
    
  ],
  "comments": [
    
  ]

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Comment: Thanks for downvote. I appreciate you so one vote from my side to you for such kind information.